# How to run ionic in the background

Tags: linux, terminal, ionic-framework

I am trying to run ionic serve in the background so I can test it via my rails app on circle ci. I thought I could do it with:

```
nohup bash -c "ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser &"
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to run it in the background?

Answer (score 8):

You could use `screen`:

```
screen -d -m -L ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want it to run in background on CI ?

It should be ok to run the command directly before your test:

```
ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser &
```

Your CI should kill all the triggered process once its done...

**Update:**

If your CI does not kill the triggered process, you could do something like this:

```
ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser &
ionicpid=$!
your_test_command_here
kill -15 $ionicpid
```

It should work on CI if all of these commands are in the same job.

Comment: The problem is that I need the command to "finish" so that circle ci can continue with the next one. The command above still takes over the command line and never finishes. Therefore circleci just waits forever until it times out and doesn't proceed with the next task. Try it out in your terminal with any ionic app. I am not quite sure how its outputting to the command line even with the appended & but it is.

Comment: Ok, I don't know about circleci, but something like this works in Jenkins. 
Are your triggering the "ionic serve" in a job and your test in another one ? Or both are in the same job ? My answer assumed that both were in the same job

Comment: I have updated my previous answer, you migth test and see if its ok with that

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The first command never stops and therefore the second command is never run. You can test this locally by first doing npm install -g cordova ionic; ionic start myApp tabs; cd myApp

Comment: The proposed solution does not work for "ionic serve". The process is unable to run in background, period. As soon as it is put in background, it suspends and stops responding.

Answer (score 0):

On CircleCI I have found this setup to work well

```
machine:
  node:
    version: v7.4.0

test:
  pre:
    - npm run webdriver-update
    - ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser --port 8101:
        background: true
    - sleep 15

  override:
    - npm run e2e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that actually works (sorry so late)

```
sleep 999999999 | ionic serve -b &
```

I think there's an easy way in ionic v3, but this works for v1