# How do I get ionic serve to work with Jenkins (trying to run end to end tests with protractor)

Tags: jenkins, ionic-framework, protractor

I've got a project written with Ionic and I'm trying to run the end to end tests (written with Protractor) on Jenkins. This is the script I'm using to run the tests:

```
#make sure ionic serve isn't running
kill -9 $(lsof -n -ti4TCP:8100)

./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl

echo starting ionic serve...
screen -d -m -L ionic serve --nolivereload --nobrowser --address localhost

echo waiting for ionic to start...
while ! curl http://localhost:8100 &>/dev/null; do :; done
echo ionic serve started

#run end to end tests

./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/e2e/protractor.config.js

echo stoping ionic...
kill -9 $(lsof -n -ti4TCP:8100)
echo stopped.

echo done
```

If I run this script on the command line it works fine. But if run through Jenkins, it gets to "waiting for ionic to start" and never finishes. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189300/how-to-run-ionic-in-the-background) question, but running "ionic serve" with an ampersand doesn't work for me. It runs and immediately quits. Using screen is the only way I've been able to get it to work.

How can I get "ionic serve" to run in the background with Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using any Task runner like Gulp or Grunt?

Comment: Are you sure, that your Jenkins installation has the respective rights to execute the curl command?