# Ionic e2e CI tests in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ionic-framework, protractor, tmux, e2e-testing

I want to achieve similar functionality to [How to run ionic in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189300/how-to-run-ionic-in-the-background) to run e2e tests of my Ionic2 application in Jenkins. The e2e tests are created with protractor.

Option 1) running in the background did not work. As suggested I tried `screen` / `tmux` like:

```
stage 'e2e testing'
        sh 'tmux new-session -d -s ionicServe'
        sh 'tmux new-session -d -s e2e'

        sh 'tmux send-keys -t ionicServe "ionic serve --nobrowser --nolivereload localhost" C-m'
        sh 'tmux send-keys -t e2e "npm run e2ej" C-m'

        sh 'tmux attach -t e2e'
```

which works great locally / in a docker container but does not work when Jenkins is executing the test cases.

Do you have any suggestions how to either **get it to work in Jenkins with tmux** or to have ionic **serve the app without the CLI** (plain gulp tasks)

Hint: a `gulp serve:before` does not seem to start the development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/blob/master/.travis.yml) is a fix. But does not seem to be as neatly integrated into Ionic CLI

```
cd www && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8100 >> python_serve.log 2>&1 &
```